# Firefox keeps updating in the background

Tags: upgrade, firefox, security

Several times a week, Firefox (version 68.0.2+build1-0ubuntu0.18.04.1) is  getting into a state where it refuses to open new tabs and instead says it has been upgraded in the background and needs to restart.

I'm pretty sure I haven't been running `apt upgrade` or anything of that sort since the Firefox instance in question was started. Is it supposed to somehow download updates from some unknown third-party source on its own, bypassing the package manager? Or have I been compromised?

Comment: Please post a screenshot when you next encounter the issue.

Comment: Mmh not that similar but in my Linux Mint with firefox 68, which I installed from source, it keeps annoying me with the updating thing every day. The firefox's guys should do something about this.

Comment: @guillermochamorro I too have Firefox direct from Mozilla. I accept the updates whenever offered and **don't** get daily messages to update.

Comment: Check your Unattended Upgrades log (/var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log) when you get a notification to see if Firefox was really upgraded quietly in the background. Firefox upgrades usually are pushed by the -security pocket, so background updates are possible with the default Ubuntu settings.

Comment: @user535733: Thanks for that pointer -- it seems that this background process was indeed upgrading through apt without being asked. I've tried to disable it with `sudo dpkg-reconfigure unattended-upgrades`, and will see if that helps. If you write that as an answer I'll happily accept.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Other than using `sudo apt-mark hold firefox` I can't see how to disable it just for Firefox without disabling the unattended upgrades process. If there is a way to exclude a package just from that background process it would be useful.

Comment: @Underverse: Well, not keeping a _web browser_ updated would be ... um, foolish. I just want the updates to happen when _I'm_ ready for them and explicitly ask apt to upgrade everything, rather than when I'm in the middle of something. Turning off the unattended upgrades accomplishes that nicely.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Unattended Upgrades

The default settings of Ubuntu have Unattended Upgrades *enabled* for new packages that are pushed by the Ubuntu Security Team (the "-security" pocket of the Ubuntu Repositories).

New releases of web browsers usually include many security fixes, so the Ubuntu Security Team pushes the new browser. Generally, new releases ONLY go into the next release of Ubuntu and are NOT backported. Web browsers, for various reasons, are a very rare exception to that practice: All supported releases of Ubuntu always get the newest web browser.

The easy way to check if Unattended Upgrades has recently upgraded your web browser is to check the log: /var/log/unattended-upgrades/unattended-upgrades.log

Answer (score 6):

Adding Firefox to `Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist` in apt configuration avoids undesired forced restarts:

```
cat <<EOF | sudo tee /etc/apt/apt.conf.d/99unattended-upgrades-firefox
Unattended-Upgrade::Package-Blacklist {
    // Disable unattended firefox upgrades to avoid undesired forced restarts
    "firefox";
};
EOF
```

Comment: The `.*` in the regex is unnecessary. It will happily match just part of the package name. In fact, if for some reason you wanted to match only `firefox` and not `firefox-dev`, `firefox-dbg`, etc., you'd have to specify `firefox$` as the regex. (It seems it does only match prefixes though, i.e. `^firefox$` is not necessary.)